# Replace space and convert to lowercase within a string

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have multiple html files, I need to replace a space and make strings lower case WITHIN a string. (all in linux)

```
Exaple:
<html> ....
<a href="bla.com/CCC C C">ddd ddd ddd</a>
<a href="bla.com/CCC C">ddd ddd ddd</a>
...
</html>

Should result in:
<html> ....
<a href="bla.com/ccc_c_c">ddd ddd ddd</a>
<a href="bla.com/ccc_c">ddd ddd ddd</a>
...
</html>
```

There are other links on the page like that but they are not bla.com they are something else so if regular exp is used (bla.com needs to be there).
CCC part is not static and can be any word!

Any one-liners that can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to replace **a** space and make strings lower case within a string

For only a **single** whitespace break then this one liner will do it:

```
sed -E 's/(bla.com\/)(\w*)\s*(.*?")/\1\L\2_\L\3/g' file
```

---

```
$ echo '<a href="bla.com/CCC C">ddd ddd ddd</a>' | sed -E 's/(bla.com\/)(\w*)\s*(.*?")/\1\L\2_\L\3/g'
<a href="bla.com/ccc_c">ddd ddd ddd</a>
```

Explanation:

```
s/            # Substitution
(bla.com\/)   # Match the domain (captured)
(\w*)         # Match the following word (captured) 
\s*           # Followed by whitespace
(.*?")        # Capture everything left upto the closing "
/             # Replace with 
\1            # The captured domain
\L\2          # Lowercase first captured word
_             # Replace the whitespace with an underscore 
\L\3          # Lowercase rest of the match
/g            # Global
```

*I'm stumped on coming up with a one liner, if as in your example there could be multiple spaces.*

Comment: thank you for response! which shell are you using? first of -E is not working in mine so i changed it to -e , second, it gives me: sed: -e expression #1, char 41: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: `-E` is extended regexp, it's probably `-r` on you implementation of `sed` just do `sed --help` and look for the flag to use extended regexp.